# Java multithreading display in sequence

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this program having 3 thread to display number 1-10. I want them to output in sequence but currently it jumping around.
example 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

I have look around in the forum , it showing Thread.yield(); will solve this issue but after i input Thread.yield(); its still the same

```
  public class ThreadTest
    {
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      MyThread t1 = new MyThread(0, 3, 10);
      MyThread t2 = new MyThread(1, 3, 10);
      MyThread t3 = new MyThread(2, 3, 10);

      t1.start();
      t2.start();
      t3.start();

   }
}

public class MyThread extends Thread {

    private int startIdx, nThreads, maxIdx;

    public MyThread(int s, int n, int m) {
        this.startIdx = s;
        this.nThreads = n;
        this.maxIdx = m;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = this.startIdx; i < this.maxIdx; i += this.nThreads) {

            System.out.println("[ID " + this.getId() + "] " + i);
            Thread.yield();

        }
    }
}




  output:
    [ID 8] 0
    [ID 8] 3
    [ID 8] 6
    [ID 10] 2
    [ID 10] 5
    [ID 10] 8
    [ID 9] 1
    [ID 8] 9

    [ID 9] 4
    [ID 9] 7
```

Comment: If you want the numbers to be printed in a sequence then don't use multiple threads!?

Comment: I want to make use of thread to speed things up

Comment: LOL. LOL. LOL. So if things happen in a certain order and not independently of each other, where on a timeline do you expect a gain?

Comment: see thread 1 start from 0 thread 2 start from 1 and thread 3 start from 3 they each have their own things to do actually so having 3 thread i can run 1 to 1 million for example faster than a single for loop

Comment: Sorry to say, but that is only true if you don't want things to happen in certain sequence. A thread will not get tired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just add a `token` to solve your problem. Runnable should got the `token` else `yield`

```
private static volatile int token = 0;

@Override
public void run() {

    for (int i = this.startIdx; i < this.maxIdx; i += this.nThreads) {

        while((token) % 3 != startIdx) Thread.yield();

        System.out.println("[ID " + this.getId() + "] " + i);
        token++;
    }

}
```

output

```
[ID 11] 0
[ID 12] 1
[ID 13] 2
[ID 11] 3
[ID 12] 4
[ID 13] 5
[ID 11] 6
[ID 12] 7
[ID 13] 8
[ID 11] 9
```

Comment: Anti-pattern that couldn’t get worse. Hardcoding the number of expected threads deep inside the code, using a polling loop for delaying the execution, etc.

Comment: my idea comes from `token ring`.

Answer (score 2):

Thread yielding and setting priority for them (as well as other operations) are only *hints* to the scheduler to determine how threads get or lose processor usage and for how long. Thus, those operations are not very usable for getting business logic, which is distributed in several threads, into a specified order.

How could your thread no. 2 know, that thread no. 1 already printed "0"? And how could your thread no. 1 know, that it is not allowed to print "3" if the number "1" and "2" are not yet printed?

If you want to have an ordered output, you must synchronize your threads accordingly. For this example, it is a bit complicated, as it is not a good example for showing thread synchronization, but it might help learning.

I will give you some hints:

1. Your threads need to know about the process of the others. So they must share common data.
2. As they also must read and update this common data, these operation must be properly synchronized.

I would suggest reading the [Java tutorial about synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html), try to adjust your program, and ask again in case of not getting further.

Comment: does it mean a simple thread process cant display 1 to 10 in sequence?

Comment: Well ... You are using the word "sequence". So you want to have a "sequential" output. Threads are used for doing "parallel" work. See ... These words are quite opposite. Using threads for sequential work needs synchronization! And that will be slower (!) than not using threads. So in this sense: No, you should not use threads.

Comment: i know threads are for parallel work,so my idea is parallel and sequential work just like A 1-10 B 11-20 C 21-30

Comment: You can achieve this with a global synchronized counter, but it really is complete nonsense, because the information must be kept outside of the threads and each of them will just execute three print methods. And not even in parallel.